# network bridge not detecting particular device, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge

I'm on 18.04 ubuntu, I have a bridge br0 setup(static 169.254.0.10) that is working with some network devices(169.254.0.40, 169.254.0.50). I have a 3rd device(169.254.0.60) that I want to connect to this bridge. I verified separately that this device works and can be pinged at that static ip(on another linux machine w/ no bridge). However, when I connect it to my computer with the bridge, nothing gets picked up.

dmesg shows nothing, brctl showmacs don't show the mac address of this device.

Are there any other ways to troubleshoot this?